# How to calculate time and space complexity of algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm

How to calculate space and time complexity of algorithms in java.

Is the total time for execution [ Using System.nanoTime() ] equals time complexity of any alogrithm or function ?

Example : Space and Time Complexity estimate of nth number in fibonacci series

Comment: 1) Sounds like homework... 2) You need to give us a bit more information. You calculate the complexity the same way as you would for C++ *(thats about as vague as your question)*.

Comment: @Nico, Just an AI and Programming challenge enthusiast.

Comment: @Ratna Dinakar - Was that the entire question?

Comment: @Nico, I want to study estimates of various algorithms before proceeding to design a library of optimized solutions ex: search of string or char in a string, break up of string etc.

Comment: @Ratna Dinakar - Ah ok, I see where you are going at. I think the easiest would be to simply post a example algorithm, then someone can go through it and show you how.

Comment: @Nico Thanks. Posted a simple example

Comment: @Ratna Dinakar - That is not an example. The complexity of a program is dependant on the code implementation. You need **code** to calculate the complexity.

Comment: @Nico, Please help me in finding what I need

Comment: @Ratna Dinakar - *sigh...* sadly that is where I draw the line. I don't think you know exactly what you want, how must we?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time complexity is a theoretical indication of scalability on an idealised machine. (its about the algorithim, not the machine)

System.nanoTime() will tell you how long something took on a specific machine, in a specific state for specific data inputs.

Time complexity is better for working out worst case values, measuring is more useful if you have a specific use case you want to consider.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the total time for execution [ Using System.nanoTime() ] equals time complexity of any alogrithm or function ?

No. When calculating the complexity order of a program, it is usually done in the *Big-O* notation. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is everything you need to know about it. With examples.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must define basic operation of the algorithm. Put a counter to calculate how many times basic operation works till your algorithm finihed working. Try to denote this counter as n.
In fibonacci series, basic operation is addition(adding last two elements give you the next)
To calculate nth number, n-1 addition must be done. So, complexity of fibonacci series is realized as O(n)

Comment: ediz.. that was just for example